# Async Storybook tests with waitFor

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, storybook

The following test passes when I run `test-storybook` locally, and my Chromatic build step passes, but in the Bitbucket pipeline, this test fails. I imagine it has to do with the async and `waitFor`. Does anyone know how to fix this?

By the way, using `async/await` and `getComputedStyle` was the only way to get these tests to work in the first place. `expect...toHaveStyle` didn't work.

```
const statuses = ['Open', 'In Progress', 'Cancelled', 'Closed'];
export const Default: PlayableStory = {
  args: {
    title: 'Filter by status',
    options: statuses.map(status => ({ value: status, label: status })),
  },
  play: async () => {
    const { getByText } = screen;
    statuses.forEach(status => expect(getByText(status)).toBeInTheDocument());

    const unSelectedBackgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)';
    const selectedBackgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)';

    async function expectChipSelected(text: string, selected = true) {
      await waitFor(() => {
        const chip = screen.getByRole('button', { name: text });
        expect(getComputedStyle(chip).backgroundColor).toEqual(
          selected ? selectedBackgroundColor : unSelectedBackgroundColor,
        );
      });
    }

    // select one
    await expectChipSelected(statuses[0], false);
    fireEvent.click(getByText(statuses[0]));
    await expectChipSelected(statuses[0]);
    
    // and more similar tests
  },
};
```

And the relevant pipeline step (copied from chromatic's docs somewhere, I think)

```yaml
- step:
    name: 'Run storybook tests'
    caches:
      - node
    script:
      - npm install --legacy-peer-deps
      - npx playwright install --with-deps
      - npm run build-storybook --silent
      - npx concurrently -k -s first -n "SB,TEST" -c "magenta,blue" \
          "npx http-server storybook-static --port 6006 --silent" \
          "npx wait-on tcp:6006 && npm run test-storybook"
```